# CSS: how to apply margin to a container with floats?

Tags: html, css, css-float

this is my age-old problem and I've never found a real solution for this so I'm finally just asking for help.

**HTML**

```
<section class="cols-2">
        <div class="wrapper">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
        </div>
</section>
<section …
```

**CSS**

```
.cols-2 .wrapper {
        margin:0;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

So I have two columns that are floated inside of my `section.cols-2`. In this case the `section` doesn't have an automatic height!

e.g. if I want another `section` with flaots immediately after this one I can't apply a margin between the two `section`s.

I don't want to apply a `height` value, I just need both `section`s to be apart from each other by a specific margin.

See my example: http://jsfiddle.net/kWtev/

Thank you for your tipps and tricks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the floats. This is not only your age-old "problem", but every sitebuilder's. But luckily, age-old problems have age-old solutions.

There are [several clearing techniques](http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/12/how-to-clear-css-floats-without-extra-markup-different-techniques-explained/) [available](http://colinaarts.com/articles/float-containment/) [on the Internet](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/float-and-clear-a-comparison-of-css-clearing-techniques/), one of the most common is using `overflow: hidden` on the container. One of the ["magic" side effects of `overflow: hidden`](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/) is clearing floats.

```
.cols-2 { overflow: hidden; }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kWtev/15/)

---

Of course you could simply use [`clear: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear), and there will be space between the containers, but the last one still won't have a nonzero height.

```
.cols-2 { clear: left; }
```

Some clearing techniques solve this by inserting another element (like an empty div or a pseudo-element) that has `clear: left` applied on it.

Comment: In the case of edding another element, it's mostlikley <div class="clear"></div> with .clear{ clear:both; }

Comment: @DennisHunink Yeah, "good" old days. There are around a thousand combinations for that technique as well.

Answer (score 1):

`.cols-2 { overflow: auto; }` will solve your issue caused by floated elements.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be using 'clearfix' for the parent container.

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }

<section class="cols-2 clearfix">
        <div class="wrapper">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
        </div>
</section>
```

You can use clearfix for any container that has floated elements in it. You need to put the clearfix css at the very end of your css file.

Just add the one class and your are done!

Comment: I'd argue this being the "best solution". Also, this won't work in IE7 and lower.

Comment: It works in all browsers. Here have a look - http://jsfiddle.net/dEW4m/3/

Your code might have not worked because the HTML has 'section' tag which is not supported by older versions of IE

Comment: My mistake, I haven't spotted the `zoom: 1;` part (you should post the link where you found this code, just to give credit).

Comment: This help is from Paul Irish and comes with his HTML5 Boilerplate - http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

can you please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kWtev/14/), it may help you

```
.cols-2 {
    margin:20px 0;
    overflow:auto;    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever thought using :

```
-webkit-column-count: 2; 
-webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
```

of course `-webkit-` prefix has to be replaced with other prefixes in order to be larger compatible...

If the behavior you are expecting allow this...

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Christophe/7sauu/)

Comment: If only [browser support](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) were there. Why did you decide to only show the `-webkit-` version? Opera and IE10 support the prefixless version, and there is also `-moz-`. Please fix it somehow.